# .intersects() method only works in certain examples

Tags: java, jpanel, intersection

I'm writing a simple program that should display "Intersecting" when two rectangles intersect. For some reason... that doesn't work with the code I have used. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {
int rectX;
int rectY;
Rectangle rect1;
Rectangle rect2;

public Game() {
    rect1 = new Rectangle(rectX, rectY, 20, 20);
    rect2 = new Rectangle(250, 250, 50, 50);
    rectX = 150;
    rectY = 150;
    setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (rect1.intersects(rect2)) {
        g.drawString("Intersecting", 75, 75);
    } else {
        g.drawString("Not Intersecting", 75, 75);
    }

    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(rect2.x, rect2.y, rect2.width, rect2.height);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(rectX, rectY, rect1.width, rect1.height);

    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    rectX = e.getX();
    rectY = e.getY();
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    rectX = e.getX();
    rectY = e.getY();

}
}
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}

public Main() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new Game());
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

But for some reason, this code does work:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame{

private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg;

int rectX, rectY;

public Main(){
    setSize(400,300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    addMouseMotionListener(new AL());
}




public void paint(Graphics g){
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(rectX, rectY, 25, 25);
    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(175, 175, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(r2.x, r2.y, r2.width, r2.height);
    g.fillRect(r1.x, r1.y, r1.width, r1.height);
    if(r1.intersects(r2)){
        g.drawString("HIT", 175, 140);
    }
    repaint();
}

public class AL extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
        rectX = e.getX()-12;
        rectY = e.getY()-12;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Main main = new Main();
}   
}﻿
```

Can anyone explain the difference between the two to me and why one does work while the other doesn't? Thanks.

Comment: You are not changing the values of the `rect1` and `rect2` objects after constructing your object. Why do you think they should intersect at all?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Arent I changing the x and y of the rectangle in my mouseMoved() method? I could be missing something, I'm still an extremely inexperienced programmer in general. :)

Comment: In the second example, you are creating a new rect every paint component call, using the rectX and rectY as the rects position. In the first one, you are not creating it every paint call but I don't see that you are moving the rect's position. Yes you are changing rectX and rectY when the mouse is moved, but in the first example you are never setting the rect's position with these variables, only during initialisation.

Comment: @user Okay, so what fix do you suggest? I would prefer it if my code didn't have to create a new Rectangle every time it painted the JPanel, but if it's necessary, I'll do it.

Comment: Use your first example, you don't want to be creating a rect every draw. The only thing you need to do is change the position of the RECT. Set rect1.x to rectX, and rect1.y to rectY whenever you change these values